# Calculate font size according to resolution in js

Tags: javascript, css

How to change the font size of the site to fit it on every screen resolution. I have searched on this but still not able to get the desired result. So please let me know the accurate formula which can calculate the font size according to resolution using java script.
 Thanks in advance

Comment: Did you tried given values in em and % instead of pixels?

Comment: ya i have set all the values in % .. but now i have to change the font size of the according the screen resolution so it the rest of % change accordingly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try putting fonts in em or percentage. Default browser font-size is 16px. You can change your document body font-size 10px as base font by making body font size `62.5% = (10/16)*(100)`

Now,

```
1em = 10px
100% = 10px
```

Answer (score 2):

Are you talking about this [**concept**](http://jsfiddle.net/matmuchrapna/2tQ5T/1/) ?

If you are, this is css only concept proof:

```
html { font-size: 62.5%; }
body { font-size: 1em;}

@media (max-width: 300px) {
    html { font-size: 70%; }
}

@media (min-width: 500px) {
    html { font-size: 80%; }
}

@media (min-width: 700px) {
    html { font-size: 120%; }
}

@media (min-width: 1200px) {
    html { font-size: 200%; }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what size you are looking for but this will get you in the ball park.
Are you looking for something like this?

```
var fontSize = Math.round((12/window.innerWidth)*1200);
document.body.style.fontSize = fontSize+'px';
```

For these window widths you will see something like this...

```
480 = 30
768 = 19
1024 = 14
1200 = 12
```

You might want to set a min so that fonts are not tiny on larger screens.